Customize Portal Browser is not compatible with Omada Controlle
I created a customized portal page for our business. However, I encountered 2 problems with my customized page on some Android devices.

On some devices, the page may load, but some elements are not working, like the dynamic content that will have greetings based on a specific time. (2ndpicture)
Other devices will not load the page at all; it shows, Sorry, the browser is not compatible. The current browser doesn't support Omada controller (3rdpicture)

When I test the HTML file locally using Chrome, everything works well. (1st picture)
I attached the HTML file that does not have media because I'm using Base64 for the images. This is a single HTML file, it contains the the CSS and JS already.
PS: I have limited knowledge on HTML, CSS, JS so most it is done by an AI
HTML file
I'm thinking the problem is on Android WebView that handles captive portal

You're mentioning pictures, yet none are present in your question. Did you forget to include them? Regarding your HTML - please post it as a part of your question, instead of having it linked to an external service. The reason for this - if the file is deleted, moved to a different location, or the service goes down, we would have no way of knowing what your code looks like. If your HTML has too much content, just trim it down to a minimal, reproducible example.
